# How can I pass a reference object (CLR) through unmanaged code without loosing the reference?

Tags: .net, c++-cli, interop

I am creatin a wrapper for an unmanaged third party library. This library allows to register callbacks. I got the callbacks working using delegates but the problem is that when registering a callback I could supply additional user data as `void*` which will not be touched by the library but passed as parameter to the callback.

In code:

```
//interface
BOOL register_callback(LPCALLBACKFN pfnCallback, void* lpvUserData);
```

C++-Cli-side:

```
bool LibWrapper::RegisterCallback()
{
    resetLastError();

    CallbackDelegate^ callback = gcnew CallbackDelegate(
        this,
        &LibWrapper::test_callback);

    GCHandle callbackHandle = GCHandle::Alloc(callback);
    IntPtr ptrCallback = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(callback);
    LPCALLBACKFN nativeCallbackPtr = \
            static_cast<LPCALLBACKFN>(ptrCallback.ToPointer());

    try
    {
        return register_callback(nativeCallbackPtr,/*void* data*/ nullptr);//!!!
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        setLastError("Unknown error when trying to register a callback.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can pass an `Object^` instead of just a `nullptr` as user data? 
The object itself could really be anything from a simple managed struct to a tree node obviously referencing other nodes, hence I'd like to find a way which does not involve creating a deep unmanaged copy of the whole object.

If it's not possible I might as well use a workaround and save my own list of requested callbacks and append the appropriate userData-Object myself. In that case it would never have to leave the managed world, but it still feels like cheating.

Comment: Personally, I'd have a (native) c++ callback that takes in `GCHandle[2]`, the first being the function pointer for the delegate, the second being the object. Then you can register whatever the heck you want.

Comment: I have to create a wrapper for third party library. The callback signature is fixed and it accepts only one void* which is given the userData that was supplied when registering the callback. If I use a GCHandle, is it guaranteed to still point to the right location once the callback is executed?

Comment: As long as the GCHandle doesn't go out of scope, yes. I'm working on an example of what i'm thinking about.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any reason why you can't just make the C# code capture the data in question in the callback? it seems weird to pass it to the function every time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can, use GCHandle::Alloc() again, get the raw pointer with GCHandle::ToIntPtr() and recover the object reference again in the callback with GCHandle::FromIntPtr().

But this just isn't necessary.  The power of a delegate over a function pointer is that it *also* captures your object reference.  The `this` argument in your CallbackDelegate constructor call.  Which ensures that your test_callback() method can be an instance function and access the object members.  Even when it is called from native code which knows beans about managed objects.  It is called with a valid *this* reference by the stub that was created when you called Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().  So just no need to use the void* argument, simply make the object a field of your class instead.

You ought to fret a bit about cleanup btw, be sure to call GCHandle::Free() when the native code can no longer make callbacks.  Not doing so leaks the managed object forever.

Comment: The class registering the callback function serves as a dispatcher and the userdata passed through the unmanaged library basically determines which one of the dispatcher's clients needs to be updated. I cant think of a good way to do this without sending any userdata at all, there'd have to be at least some kind of a reference to the target object. The easiest solution would probably be using Alloc again, an alternative would be saving the target objects in a list and pass each object's list index as user data. Is there any (dis-)advantage in one of these alternatives?

Comment: That's a different kettle of fish, you need *one* function pointer for *many* managed objects.  Yes, pass the index of the object in a `List<LibWrapper^>^`.

Comment: This is the answer. Nevertheless could you tell me why you'd recommend using an index instead of using Alloc?